# Boost::thread::interrupt() behaves differently for different interruption points. Why?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-thread

I am currently writing a DLL that uses boost threads. I've had issues with using boost::thread::interrupt() and catching the thread_interrupted exception. With some interruption ponts, the interruption is thrown and caught in the thread and with others, the interrupt is thrown where thread.interrupt() is called. Why does this happen? I have written a basic example to illustate my point, it is at the bottom of this post

The program starts a thread that uses one of the worker functions that each have a different interruption point in them. When the user presses enter, the thread is interrupted and the program closes. Before each statement that is printed, the thread id is printed so that we can see what is happening.

I expect something like this:

```
13c4 main thread

790 worker thread
790 thread iteration 1 Press Enter to stop
790 thread iteration 2 Press Enter to stop
790 thread iteration 3 Press Enter to stop
790 Thread is stopped in ThreadFunction
13c4 main: thread ended

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.200 s
Press any key to continue.
```

where the main thread runs, in parallel with the worker thread. When the user presses enter, the interrupt is called in the main thread but caught in the worker thread. The thread is then destroyed. The main thread then continues and the program exits.

What I am seeing with all the interruption points I've tried (except interruption_point()) is that the interrupt is caught in the main thread and it seems as though its is the worker thread that continues the execution of the main thread. Like so:

```
1364 main thread
964 worker thread
964 thread iteration 1 Press Enter to stop
964 thread iteration 2 Press Enter to stop
964 thread iteration 3 Press Enter to stop

964 Thread is joined
964 main: thread ended

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 1.510 s
Press any key to continue.
```

What is causing this? How can I catch the interrupt in the worker function when using a condition variable, for example? Have I made a mistake somewhere?

My code:

```
#define BOOST_THREAD_USE_LIB 1
#define BOOST_SYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED 1
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501
#define WINVER 0x0501

#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void ThreadFunctionSleep()
{
    cout <<  boost::this_thread::get_id() << " worker thread " << endl;
    int counter = 0;

    while(1)
    {
        cout <<  boost::this_thread::get_id() << " thread iteration " << ++counter << " Press Enter to stop" << endl;

        try
        {
            boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(5000));
        }
        catch(boost::thread_interrupted&)
        {
            cout <<  boost::this_thread::get_id() << " Thread is stopped in ThreadFunction " << endl;
            return;
        }

    }




}

void ThreadFunctionSleep2()
{
    cout <<  boost::this_thread::get_id() << " worker thread " << endl;
    int counter = 0;

    try
    {
        cout <<  boost::this_thread::get_id() << " thread iteration " << ++counter << " Press Enter to stop" << endl;

        while(1)
        {
            boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(5000));
        }

    }
    catch(boost::thread_interrupted&)
    {
        cout <<  boost::this_thread::get_id() << " Thread is stopped in ThreadFunction " << endl;
        return;
    }





}

void ThreadFunctionInterruptionPoint()
{
    cout <<  boost::this_thread::get_id() << " worker thread " << endl;
    int counter = 0;

    while(1)
    {
        cout <<  boost::this_thread::get_id() << " thread iteration " << ++counter << " Press Enter to stop" << endl;

        try
        {

            boost::this_thread::interruption_point();

        }
        catch(boost::thread_interrupted&)
        {
            cout <<  boost::this_thread::get_id() << " Thread is stopped in ThreadFunction " << endl;
            return;
        }

    }

}

bool myPredicate()
{
    return false;
}

boost::condition_variable full;
boost::condition_variable empty;
boost::mutex fullMut;
boost::mutex emptyMut;

void waitedConditionVariable()
{


    try
    {
        while(1)
        {
            boost::system_time const timeout=boost::get_system_time()+ boost::posix_time::milliseconds(1000);
            boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(fullMut);
            std::cout << boost::this_thread::get_id()<< "  waiting for condition variable or for timeout" << std::endl;


            if (full.timed_wait(lock, timeout, myPredicate))
            {


                std::cout << boost::this_thread::get_id()<< "  condition variable signalled " << std::endl;

            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << boost::this_thread::get_id()<< " condition variable  timeout. "  << std::endl;

            }



        }
    }
    catch(boost::thread_interrupted & )
    {
        std::cout<< boost::this_thread::get_id() << " waitedConditionVariable thread_interrupted " << std::endl;
        return;

    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {

        std::cerr << boost::this_thread::get_id()<< " waitedConditionVariable Thread "
                  << " caught std::exception" << e.what() << std::endl;
                  return;

    }
    catch(...)
    {
        std::cout<< boost::this_thread::get_id() << " waitedConditionVariable other" << std::endl;
        return;

    }

}

void waitedConditionVariable2()
{



    while(1)
    {
        try
        {
            boost::system_time const timeout=boost::get_system_time()+ boost::posix_time::milliseconds(1000);
            boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(fullMut);
            std::cout << boost::this_thread::get_id()<< "  waiting for condition variable or for timeout" << std::endl;


            if (full.timed_wait(lock, timeout, myPredicate))
            {


                std::cout << boost::this_thread::get_id()<< "  condition variable signalled " << std::endl;

            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << boost::this_thread::get_id()<< " condition variable  timeout. "  << std::endl;

            }



        }
        catch(boost::thread_interrupted & )
        {
            std::cout<< boost::this_thread::get_id() << " waitedConditionVariable thread_interrupted " << std::endl;
            return;

        }
        catch (std::exception& e)
        {

            std::cerr << boost::this_thread::get_id()<< " waitedConditionVariable Thread "
                      << " caught std::exception" << e.what() << std::endl;
            return;

        }
        catch(...)
        {
            std::cout<< boost::this_thread::get_id() << " waitedConditionVariable other" << std::endl;
            return;

        }
    }


}

void normalConditionVariable()
{

    try
    {
        boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(fullMut);
        while(1)
        {


            std::cout << boost::this_thread::get_id()<< " waiting for condition variable " << std::endl;
            full.wait(lock);

            std::cout << boost::this_thread::get_id()<< " wait done "  << std::endl;

        }
    }
    catch(boost::thread_interrupted & )
    {
        std::cout<< boost::this_thread::get_id() << " normalConditionVariable thread_interrupted " << std::endl;
        return;

    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {

        std::cerr << boost::this_thread::get_id()<< " normalConditionVariable Thread "
                  << " caught std::exception" << e.what() << std::endl;
        return;

    }
    catch(...)
    {
        std::cout<< boost::this_thread::get_id() << " normalConditionVariable other" << std::endl;
        return;

    }
}

void normalConditionVariable2()
{

    while(1)
    {
        boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(fullMut);
        try
        {


            std::cout << boost::this_thread::get_id()<< " waiting for condition variable " << std::endl;
            full.wait(lock);

            std::cout << boost::this_thread::get_id()<< " wait done "  << std::endl;

        }
        catch(boost::thread_interrupted & )
        {
            std::cout<< boost::this_thread::get_id() << " normalConditionVariable thread_interrupted " << std::endl;
            return;

        }
        catch (std::exception& e)
        {

            std::cerr << boost::this_thread::get_id()<< " normalConditionVariable Thread "
                      << " caught std::exception" << e.what() << std::endl;
            return;

        }
        catch(...)
        {
            std::cout<< boost::this_thread::get_id() << " normalConditionVariable other" << std::endl;
            return;

        }
    }

}



int main()
{
    cout <<  boost::this_thread::get_id() << " main thread " << endl;
    // Start thread
    //use thes functions:
    // ThreadFunctionSleep
    // ThreadFunctionSleep2
    //ThreadFunctionInterruptionPoint
    //ThreadFunctionInterruptionPoint2
    // waitedConditionVariable
    // waitedConditionVariable2
    // normalConditionVariable
    // normalConditionVariable2
    boost::thread t(&waitedConditionVariable2);


    // Wait for Enter
    char ch;
    cin.get(ch);

    // Ask thread to stop
    try
    {
        t.interrupt();
    }
    catch(boost::thread_interrupted&)
    {
        cout <<  boost::this_thread::get_id() << " Thread is stopped" << endl;

    }

    // Join - wait when thread actually exits
    try
    {
        t.join();
    }
    catch(boost::thread_interrupted&)
    {
        cout <<  boost::this_thread::get_id() << " Thread is joined" << endl;

    }
    catch(...){
        cout <<  boost::this_thread::get_id() << " other exception" << endl;

    }

    cout <<  boost::this_thread::get_id() << " main: thread ended" << endl;




    return 0;
}
```

I am using boost 1.53.0 and MinGW 4.4.1. I am using the runtime-link-static, multithreading libraries for boost::thread and boost::system

Thanks for your help

Comment: Did you get this figured out?

Answer (score 0):

One should re-throw the exception, or the `boost::thread` will not really interrupted.

Try the code below. And you can try different `join()` positions to see the different output which shows the state of the thread.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

void foo()
{
    while(true) try
    {
        boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
        std::cout << "Thread is running..." << std::endl;
    }


    catch (boost::thread_interrupted&)
    {
       std::cout << "The thread is interrupted" << std::endl;

       throw boost::thread_interrupted();
    }

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    boost::thread t(foo);

    std::cout << "Press Enter to quit..." << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
    t.interrupt();
    //t.join();

    if (!t.try_join_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(1)))
    {
        std::cout << "Thread is running." << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Thread is not running." << std::endl;
    }

    //t.join();
    boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(1000));

    // The out put should be "Thread is running.", because thread is not joinalb, the test function itself is wrong.
    if (!t.try_join_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(1)))
    {
        std::cout << "Thread is running." << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Thread is not running." << std::endl;
    }
}
```